# Convert Expression<Action<T>> to Expression<Func<T>>

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have `Expression<Action<T>>` where Action is call of function, but function result is not used. Let's consider the following code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public class MyArg
        {
            public int Data { get; set; }
        }

        public class MyExecutor
        {
            public bool Executed { get; set; }

            public int MyMethod(int simpleArg, MyArg complexArg)
            {
                int result = simpleArg + complexArg.Data;
                this.Executed = true;
                return result;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Expression<Action<MyExecutor>> expr = t => t.MyMethod(2, new MyArg { Data = 3 });

            var executor = new MyExecutor();
            Action<MyExecutor> action = expr.Compile();
            action(executor);
            Console.WriteLine(executor.Executed); // true
        }
    }
}
```

There can lot of different actions, with different number of arguments. In all cases I have only such kind of `expr` which always calls a function and that function always returns the same type, in my example above it is `int`.

I need to have something like this:

```
static Expression<Func<MyExecutor, int>> ToExpressionOfFunc(Expression<Action<MyExecutor>> expr)
{
    // TODO
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

to be able to make a call like this:

```
    Expression<Func<MyExecutor, int>> funcExpr = ToExpressionOfFunc(expr);
    Func<MyExecutor, int> func = funcExpr.Compile();
    int result = func(executor);
    Console.WriteLine(result); // should print 5
```

I have a feeling that this should be possible but have no ideas where to start from. I see in debug that there is an expr.Body.Method with desired ReturnType of Int32, but not clear how to extract it properly to the new `Expression<Func>`.

Comment: Step 1: write both lines of code `Expression<Action<MyExecutor>> expr = t => t.MyMethod(2, new MyArg { Data = 3 });` and `Expression<Func<MyExecutor,int>> ret_expr = t => t.MyMethod(2, new MyArg { Data = 3 });` Step 2: look at both in the debugger to see the difference in the construction of the expression tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simple, just create a new `Expression<Func<MyExecutor, int>>` using the body and parameters from the existing expression:

```
static Expression<Func<MyExecutor, int>> ToExpressionOfFunc(Expression<Action<MyExecutor>> expr)
{
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<MyExecutor, int>>(expr.Body, expr.Parameters);
}
```

Note that this throws an exception if `expr` is not of return type `int`.